# Custom SerDe not supported by Impala, what's the best way to query files in CSV w/double quotes?

Tags: csv, hadoop, double-quotes, impala

I have a CSV data with each field surronded with double quotes. When I created
Hive table used serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
When above table is queried in Impala I am getting error SerDe not found.

I added the CSV Serde JAR file in /usr/lib/impala/lib folder.

Later studied in Impala documentation that Impala does not support custom
SERDE. In such case how I can overcome this issue such that my CSV data
with quotes is taken care. I want to use CSV Serde because it takes of
commas in values which is a legitimate field vavlue.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Can you use Hive? 
If so, here is an approach that might work. `CREATE` your table as an `EXTERNAL TABLE` in Hive and use your `SERDE` in the right place of the CREATE Statement (I think you need something like ROW FORMAT SERDE your_serde_here at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement).  Before this you might need to do:

```
ADD JAR 'hdfs:///path/to/your_serde.jar'
```

Note that the jar should be somewhere in hdfs and triple /// needed for it to work...

Then, still in Hive, duplicate the table into another table that is stored in a format with which Impala can easily work, such as PARQUET. Something like the following does this copying:

```
CREATE TABLE copy_of_table 
   STORED AS PARQUET AS
   SELECT * FROM your_original_table
```

Now in Impala use [INVALIDATE METADATA](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.0/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html#invalidate_metadata) to mark the metadata as stale:

```
INVALIDATE METADATA copy_of_table
```

You should be all set to happily work with copy_of_table in Impala now.

Let me know whether this works, as I might have do to something like this in the near future.

Comment: The correct query is `CREATE TABLE copy_of_table STORED AS PARQUET  AS  SELECT * FROM your_original_table` otherwise Hive return a syntax exception.

Answer (score 1):

Within Hive

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.my_serde_table_impala AS SELECT FROM mydb.my_serde_table
```

Within Impala

```
INVALIDATE METADATA mydb.my_serde_table_impala
```

Add these steps to include dropping the _impala table first with whatever populates or ingests files for the serde table.

Impala bypasses MapReduce, unlike Hive. So Impala can't/doesn't use the SerDe the way MapReduce does.

Answer (score 0):

Now the default SerDe class is `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe` and it is supported by Impala. Unfortunately it has much less features, for exmaple, it does not support escape chars.